# How to get the url that redirected me to index/home page

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, http-headers

Some how my page is redirected to the index/home.php and i am unable to find which part of code is redirecting it. Already tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on echoing in index page, but it is of no use. because it showing the url of index/home page.
I think, some of my code is reseting the Session. Searched a lot, but did not find any solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check Apache error.log and Firebug's Net tab

Comment: @anubhava not getting any error